# Where are the javadocs for Lotus' Notes.jar?

Tags: java, javadoc, lotus-notes

I need to use Lotus Notes/Domino as a data source from a Java application.  The documentation at IBM says that the `Notes.jar` contains everything I will need, but where are the javadocs?

Comment: Where did you get Notes.jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the APIs are detailed in the [Domino Designer Help](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/dominodesigner/).

Comment: dacracot is asking for the associated javadocs one normally expects with a java api when you're coding in eclipse. IBM never published this information in the format he's asking. The domino designer help is the only source. Check Ascalonian's answer... but given this question is more than 2yr's old, it probably doesn't matter now.

Comment: Upvoted, as I think the downvote was a little unfair... The help files are really the only place IBM places documentation that is easy to get to.

Answer (score 4):

From what I quickly read, there isn't a set javadocs available. However, I stumbled upon [this utility](http://domino-javadoc.sourceforge.net/) that generates them for you. Would this help?

Answer (score 3):

Here comes `Notes.jar` of [Domino 8.5 Java API document](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS_JAVA.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [DeveloperWorks help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.javadoc/javadoc_intro.html)