# Developing Domino Java Addin-Task

Tags: java, lotus-domino

i need to develop a Domino Java Addin-Task, do you know if there is some documentation about?
Like how MessageQueue Works, and Notes.jar documentation?

Thanks to all,
BR

Luca

Comment: This post on SO will help you to find the [Notes.jar Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848243/where-are-the-javadocs-for-lotus-notes-jar) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Java_access_pt1/) are some information about getting Java Access to Notes Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best place to start is Julian's code:

http://www.nsftools.com/tips/JavaAddinTest.java

My good friend Andy Brunner made this presentation in german which is good:

http://www.entwicklercamp.de/konferenz/ent2009.nsf/bc36cf8d512621e0c1256f870073e627/6ebb5e1b95374ea5c12574fe00501b05/$FILE/T3S7-Java%20Add-In%20Servertask.pdf

and he has also made some helper classes to avoid the biggest headaches with Message queuing:

http://abdata.ch/abdata/web.nsf/JAddin.xsp

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's answer assumes you want to use the unsupported `lotus.notes.addins.JavaServerAddin` class.  That's certainly one option, but you may also want to consider using the DOTS framework.  DOTS is an acronym for Domino OSGi Tasklet Service.  It's available on OpenNTF as an extension to Domino 8.5.2.  Even better, it is built into Domino 9.0.

Here's a very good video introduction to DOTS:

http://www.notesin9.com/2012/12/04/notesin9-093-introduction-to-dots/

If you are using Domino 9.0, you can ignore some of the installation steps in the video.  As I said, DOTS is built into 9.0, so those steps are obsolete.  Also, there's a lot more info on DOTS out there.  I recommend searching for "IBM Domino OSGi Tasklet Service".

Answer (score 0):

I've already did the first approach and Julians code is indeed a good starting point. But be warned: This path is dark and full of pitfalls.
Get the C-Api documentation. The undocumented Java functions in general reflect well (ok not well but usefull) documented C functions. And the addin task example in the api toolkit gives a good impression on how things work.
BTW: Because an addin task runs for a long time, recycling is crucial. If you don't want to bother with that use the recycler: recycler.sourceforge.io